# Java how can i enable ssl debug

Tags: java, ssl

i am using a java program to send an http request to a website with `SSL (https)` to do more exactly "https://www.iplocation.net/", so i am sending request with proxy but i have continually errors with connection, i am sending the request with Jaunt API http://jaunt-api.com/ i get connection 1 or 2 time but then i get error connection, searching in google i read that a guy say that i have to `Enable SSL debugging` and he say that i have to use 
`-Djava.net.debug=all` but he don't explain anything and i don't know if that is a code or a configuration in java, if someone know how can i enable `ssl` debugging please can explain me step by step? i just wanna do (`HTTPS`) resquest and don't get always error connections.

[image]

Comment: which application server

Comment: "-Djava.net.debug=all" perhaps will only help in case you are using HttpURLConnection or something similar

Comment: @JunedAhsan It will help if you are using anything from JSSE upwards.

Comment: @OP Have you considered consulting the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Debug)? Your *actual* question is why the error? If those are your messages they are not adequate. You need to log the actual exception, its message, and its stacktrace. Not something you dreamt up yourself to replace it. If they are Jaunt's messages, they are a disgrace.

Comment: @EJP Thank you for insight. Really helped to increase my knowledge. Cheers!